# Using lm-sensors to get temperature

Tags: c++, c

I've done an app to communicate with an arduino board that shows the info i send in a LCD. The problem is that i want to send the CPU temp, i know the best is use lm-sensors (i'm using linux) but don't know how, it doesn't have any example, so, does somebody know how to use it or where i can get an example?

Answer (score 7):

If the lm_sensors modules are already loaded, the temperatures should be accessible in files from sysfs (for example: `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_input`) that you can read with standard C/C++ file functions.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface

Answer (score 0):

`lm-sensors` also provides the `libsensor` library. This [repo](https://github.com/ros-drivers/linux_peripheral_interfaces/tree/kinetic/libsensors_monitor) shows a way to use `libsensors4-dev` to get temperature, voltage, and others.